# What framework for an Android / IOS offline application?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, frameworks, offlineapps

I would like to know which framework to use for coding for Android and IOS 2 in 1, a completely offline application (backup in the cache). This is a rather simple application, like a note or todo list.

I was going to start using Cordova (or PhoneGap), but I'm not sure I can create a completely offline application given the languages ​​used.
Am I wrong ?

If not, which framework to use? I know for example that React-Native allows to code a 2-in-1 application, Android and IOS, can we do with React-Native a simple application totally offline?

Or do you have a good framework to advise ? (for a simple application for Android & IOS completely Offline).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be possible to create the application like a local web project, you will need to load all of the HTML/JS/CSS files into a WKWebView from the application's bundle.  I do not suggest this however.   I think you would be better using Cordova or PhoneGap, you might also want to checkout [xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) . My real suggestion would be to write the application in the native Android and iOS SDK's :) Since it's just a todo list it wouldn't be very hard to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova / PhoneGap can create multi-platform offline mobile apps with no problem. The apps you create are essentially W3C widgets (i.e., offline web applications with all the resources packaged and downloaded on the mobile device), with access to the mobile device's features available through plugins.

Data can be stored in a number of locations on the device: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html. I have our data in an sqlite database, using a variant of the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin.

Cordova itself is agnostic about what HTML/JS frameworks you use. I personally use [BackboneJS](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/06/building-modular-mobile-phonegap-apps-with-backbone-js-requirejs-and-topcoat/) (actually, an extension of Backbone called [MarionetteJS](http://shout.setfive.com/2014/04/02/javascript-phonegap-with-backbone-and-marionette/) that adds a Controller to the MV pattern Backbone supplies), but I know that [React](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/12/sample-mobile-application-with-react-and-cordova/) and [AngularJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-your-first-mobile-app-with-angularjs-and-ionic) are popular as well.

I would start by playing around with Christophe Coenraets' excellent tutorial here: https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/

By the way, if you're just looking to create a TODO app in Cordova, there are a few out there already. Here's one that might be worth looking at: https://github.com/liveoak-io/liveoak-example-todomvc-cordova